# How do I find all elements of one array that are not present in another array?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, grep

The answers I found while researching point towards using `grep`, especially since the arrays are not longer than 20-40 elements.

I have two arrays of filenames, `@allfiles` and `@keepfiles`. I want to delete the files of which the filenames are only present in `@allfiles`. `@allfiles` has more elements than `@keepfiles`.

I would like to use something like:

```
for(my $ii=0;$ii<=$allfilesSize-1; $ii++)
   {
    # if the current element of @allfiles is not in @keepfiles, delete the file
    unless(grep(@allfiles->[$ii],@keepfiles))
    {
        my $command = "del <value of @allfiles->[$ii]>";
        system($command);
    }
 }
```

I can't figure out how to write the `grep` statement. 
Either I don't know how to reference the value of the array element correctly, or not write the regex, or very possibly both. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `array_minus` from [Array::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils#array_minus) on CPAN.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils 'array_minus';
use Data::Printer;

my @allfiles = ('a'..'z');
my @keepfiles = qw(a e i o u);

my @delete_files = array_minus(@allfiles, @keepfiles);

p @delete_files;
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [0]  "b",
    [1]  "c",
    [2]  "d",
    [3]  "f",
    [4]  "g",
    [5]  "h",
    [6]  "j",
    [7]  "k",
    [8]  "l",
    [9]  "m",
    [10] "n",
    [11] "p",
    [12] "q",
    [13] "r",
    [14] "s",
    [15] "t",
    [16] "v",
    [17] "w",
    [18] "x",
    [19] "y",
    [20] "z"
]
```

---

Alternatively you can use a lookup hash, which is a very common idiom in Perl. You build up a hash first and then use the `exists` keyword to check if a key is present.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @allfiles = ('a'..'z');
my @keepfiles = qw(a e i o u);

my %lookup = map { $_ => 1 } @keepfiles;
my @delete_files = grep { ! exists $lookup{$_} && $_ } @allfiles;

p @delete_files;
```

Output is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Just use the real arrays, and replace the `print` statement with your `system` command.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @all = qw(a b c d e f);
my @some = qw(c f);

for my $file (@all){
    if (! grep /^$file\z/, @some){
        print "$file\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite inefficient to do it that way - `grep` is a looping construct, so you're iterating `@some` a lot more than you probably need to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Sobrique, I'm always looking for it, and it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two variants suggested by @simbabque are not exactly equal. 
The difference is caused by using 
`&& $_` in the expression  `my @delete_files = grep { ! exists $lookup{$_} && $_ } @allfiles;`   in the second variant.

code `&& $_` as i understand is used just to avoid coping values like 0 or '' (empty string) from big array (@allfiles) to output array (@delete_files). While Array::Utils::array_minus() doesn't provide such functionality.
if you ommit code `&& $_` you will recieve equal variants.